# Problema con la etiqueta height

Tags: css, height

Genero un div con una anchura y altura determinados y dentro de este un parrafo al que indico width:50% y height:50%. Como era de esperar el contenedor parrafo adquiere una anchura y altura del 50% respecto del div. Hasta ahi todo bien........

Pero si elimino el div, el contenedor parrafo adquiere una anchura del 50% de la ventana del Navegador (como era de esperar) pero no se modifica su altura a un 50% de la altura del Navegador. Pq?????

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>anchura</title>
            
    <style>         
      body{
        margin:0;
      }
      p {
        margin:0;
        border:solid 4px blue;
        width:50%;
        height:50%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Esto es un parrafo</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Un saludo

Comment: agrega `position: absolute`, falta una referencia para las medidas.

Answer (score 0):

La Propiedad height establece la altura de los elementos de bloque.
Si se declara en porcentaje, hace referencia a la altura del elemento en el que se encuentra (a su padre).

Si este elemento contenedor no tiene establecida una altura de forma explícita y el elemento para el que se define la altura no está posicionado de forma absoluta, se ignora la altura en porcentaje y se sustituye por el valor auto.